# Can i update the entire table without having to use SET

Tags: php, mysqli

I have an admin page that loads all the information ready into its input fields. The user can then edit that infomation and submit it back to the database.

Can i not use a similar sql query to `INSERT INTO`?

Something like `("UPDATE tableName WHERE username = '$username_entry")`

and all the fields refresh all the fields in that row.

I have this code from my `INSERT` :

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO business_info (timestamp,
     username,
     password,
     business_name,
     address1,
     address2,
     address3,
     address4,
     postcode,
     tel,
     email1,
     email2,
     website,
     Facebook,
     twitter,
     opening_monday_from,
     opening_monday_to,
     opening_tuesday_from,
     opening_tuesday_to,
     opening_wednesday_from,
     opening_wednesday_to,
     opening_thursday_from,
     opening_thursday_to,
     opening_friday_from,
     opening_friday_to,
     opening_saturday_from,
     opening_saturday_to,
     opening_sunday_from,
     opening_sunday_to,
     business_type,
     business_description,
     managers_message,
     image1,
     image2,
     image3,
     image4,
     image5) 

     VALUES (NOW(), %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",

    GetSQLValueString($_POST['username_entry'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($hashPass, "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['business_name'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['address1'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['address2'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['address3'], "text"),
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['address4'], "text"),
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['postcode'], "text"),
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['tel'], "text"),
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['email1'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['email2'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['website'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['facebook'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['twitter'], "text"),  
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_monday_from'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_monday_to'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_tuesday_from'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_tuesday_to'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_wednesday_from'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_wednesday_to'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_thursday_from'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_thursday_to'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_friday_from'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_friday_to'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_saturday_from'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_saturday_to'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_sunday_from'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['opening_sunday_to'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['business_type'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['business_description'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['managers_message'], "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($insert_upload1, "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($insert_upload2, "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($insert_upload3, "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($insert_upload4, "text"), 
    GetSQLValueString($insert_upload5, "text")); 




    if (mysqli_query($link, $insertSQL)) {
        echo "New record created successfully $username_entry";



    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $insertSQL . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
    }

    mysqli_close($link);
```

Is there any way i can amend this to work for my situation?

Comment: I know i need prepared statements to avoid SQL injection. This is not public and will add them when necessary.

Comment: As a side note you should never insert into a table with specifying the columns.

Comment: The syntax for UPDATE is different from INSERT, but the answer is yes, you can do it all in a single query. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: What does the manual say? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html - Have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html - So, pretty hard to get away from SET. *"Can i update the entire table without having to use SET"* - Therefore and to answer the question; no, not with those.

Comment: If i do use SET can i use variables? Say assign each $_POST[''] to a new variable and SET each column individually that way. Does anyone know the Syntax and way that would be written?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a primary key that will be matched, you can use a REPLACE INTO query. ([docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html))

This will delete the old row prior to doing an insert.

However this is not an efficient way to go about it.  What is your reasoning for not wanting to use an UPDATE .. SET query?  The number of columns you have in the table?

Edit (to address the comment):
Assuming the form you have for your admin page have all the input names set to the exact column names in mysql.  You could just do:

```
$query = "UPDATE business_info SET";
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $query .= " " . $key . " = '" . $value . "'";
}
$query .= " WHERE some_condition='value'";
```

Or if you are using PDO:

```
$query = "UPDATE business_info SET";
$values = []
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $query .= " " . $key . " = ?";
    $values[] = $value;
}
$query .= " WHERE some_condition='value'";
```

This will build the update query based on your post values.

Note: Didn't escape any input, make sure you do add that back in.

Comment: There are a lot of collumns to be updated and im unsure of the best way to write it with variables assigned by $_POST input fields. I dont mind using UPDATE SET, I just dont know the proper way to write it for my situation.

Comment: Updated answer with a snippet to help build your query, hope that helps

Comment: I have all the $_POST names set tot the same as the columns. So how do apply this method to my code? Sorry, im new to mysqli. Thanks for your help on this one.

Comment: Basically you are just using the structure of the post data to build your query.  You post is being returned in the format of "column name" => "new value", so you just need to iterate over it and manipulate the data into a usable query.  In my comment above is an example of a loop to do that.  Is there something more specific you still had a question about?